# java.net SocketException derived from a Service. How to handle so the app does not crash?

Tags: java, android

I have a Service that queires a Rest webservice on a regular basis.  However, when the internet is not available my app crashes.  i have tried to handle it but to no avail.  Please can someone advise?

I've tried the following to handle the exceptions:

```
private ArrayList<Article> doDownLoad(String url) {
    Log.d("NewArticleNotification_Service", "doDownload() called...");

    articles = new ArrayList<Article>();
    try {
        return loadXmlFromNetwork(url);
    } catch (XmlPullParserException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketTimeoutException e) {
        Log.i("DownloadXmlTask", "SocketTimeoutException");

        e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (SocketException e) {
        Log.i("DownloadXmlTask", "SocketException");
       /*re-send the intent */

        Intent re_subIntent = new Intent(this, NewArticleNotification_Service.class);
        re_subIntent.putExtra(NewArticleNotification_Service.POSITION_STRING, positionS);
        re_subIntent.putExtra(NewArticleNotification_Service.REQUEST_CODE, reqCode);
        startService(re_subIntent);

           Log.e(TAG, "intent is RE-SENT!");


        e.printStackTrace();

    }catch (UnknownHostException e){
        Log.e("DownloadXmlTask", "UnknownHostException");
    e.printStackTrace();

    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

This is my stack trace:

```
  02-09 14:36:25.393  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed I/DownloadXmlTask﹕ SocketException
  02-09 14:36:25.400  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed E/NewArticleNotification_Service﹕ intent is RE-SENT!
  02-09 14:36:25.401  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ java.net.SocketException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
  02-09 14:36:25.402  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.maybeThrowAfterRecvfrom(IoBridge.java:545)
  02-09 14:36:25.402  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:509)
  02-09 14:36:25.402  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:489)
  02-09 14:36:25.402  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl.access$000(PlainSocketImpl.java:46)
  02-09 14:36:25.402  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at java.net.PlainSocketImpl$PlainSocketInputStream.read(PlainSocketImpl.java:241)
  02-09 14:36:25.402  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(BufferedInputStream.java:283)
  02-09 14:36:25.403  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.okhttp.internal.http.HttpTransport$ChunkedInputStream.read(HttpTransport.java:441)
  02-09 14:36:25.403  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(InputStreamReader.java:233)
  02-09 14:36:25.403  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.fillBuffer(KXmlParser.java:1506)
  02-09 14:36:25.403  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.peekType(KXmlParser.java:986)
  02-09 14:36:25.404  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:346)
  02-09 14:36:25.405  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at org.kxml2.io.KXmlParser.next(KXmlParser.java:310)
  02-09 14:36:25.406  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.XmlParser.skip(XmlParser.java:382)
  02-09 14:36:25.407  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.XmlParser.readResult(XmlParser.java:181)
  02-09 14:36:25.408  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.XmlParser.readResultList(XmlParser.java:93)
  02-09 14:36:25.410  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.XmlParser.readResponseWarpper(XmlParser.java:50)
  02-09 14:36:25.410  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.XmlParser.parse(XmlParser.java:29)
  02-09 14:36:25.411  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.NewArticleNotification_Service.loadXmlFromNetwork(NewArticleNotification_Service.java:304)
  02-09 14:36:25.411  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.NewArticleNotification_Service.doDownLoad(NewArticleNotification_Service.java:252)
  02-09 14:36:25.412  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at com.android.lifesci_pubmed.NewArticleNotification_Service.onHandleIntent(NewArticleNotification_Service.java:140)
  02-09 14:36:25.412  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at android.app.IntentService$ServiceHandler.handleMessage(IntentService.java:65)
  02-09 14:36:25.412  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
  02-09 14:36:25.413  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:136)
  02-09 14:36:25.413  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at android.os.HandlerThread.run(HandlerThread.java:61)
  02-09 14:36:25.414  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ Caused by: libcore.io.ErrnoException: recvfrom failed: ETIMEDOUT (Connection timed out)
  02-09 14:36:25.416  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.recvfromBytes(Native Method)
  02-09 14:36:25.416  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.Posix.recvfrom(Posix.java:141)
  02-09 14:36:25.417  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.BlockGuardOs.recvfrom(BlockGuardOs.java:164)
  02-09 14:36:25.418  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ at libcore.io.IoBridge.recvfrom(IoBridge.java:506)
  02-09 14:36:25.419  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/System.err﹕ ... 22 more
  02-09 14:36:25.420  10998-11070/com.example.lifesci_pubmed W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=11: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x41611d40)
```

I have the following at the top of my Service file to check for internet connectivity:

```
@Override
protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
    Log.i("NewArticleNotification_Service", "Received an intent from   SearchTerm_fragment: " + intent);

    // Retrieve intent extras.
    positionS = intent.getIntExtra(POSITION_STRING, 0);
    reqCode = intent.getIntExtra(REQUEST_CODE, 0);

    Log.e("NewArticleNotification_Service", "INTENT RECEIVED! Intent_Extra info. position: " + positionS
            + " requestCode: " + reqCode);

    // Check network availability
    ConnectivityManager cm = (ConnectivityManager) getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
    @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
    boolean isNetWorkAvailable = cm.getBackgroundDataSetting() && cm.getActiveNetworkInfo() != null;
    if (!isNetWorkAvailable) {
```